# Custom doman (with SSL) for Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that I would like to expose via SSL and also using a custom domain name. Ex:

My cloud functions: https://us-east1-xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/my-function

custom name: https://my-custom-domain/my-function

I configured a CName for it, but I am getting an SSL error message:

(51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name...

Based on my research, an option is to use firebase.

Is there any other way to do it? (I am not using firebase currently, I would like to avoid to bring more complexity to the solution)

Thanks

Comment: You can configure Firebase Hosting to proxy requests to your custom domain to Cloud Functions, as described in the duplicate.

Comment: the intention of my question was to explore other alternatives than firebase. I can't understand why it was closed. @DougStevenson

Comment: Did you click through and read the duplicate?  Does it answer your question?  If not, please ask another question, and be sure to clearly explain what is missing from the duplicate.  If your question is looking for product recommendations, that is off-topic for Stack Overflow.